# How does the mass flow rate through an annular fin tube affect the heat transfer Q?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer

I have a fluid flowing through an annular finned tube. The heat transfer (cooling of the fluid in the pipe) is done by natural convection. I am curious about the relationship with how the mass flow rate of the fluid in the pipe affect the amount of heat transfer which can be achieved.

Comment: You want to look up the sieder-tate correlation for forced convection heat transfer in pipes

Comment: This question seems to be related and might help: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/5995/33

Comment: @hazzey the problem in the link has the fins inside the tube.